# most suited search algorithm?

Tags: search, indexing, tree, gpgpu

I'm now facing a problem and I'm not sure what the right solution is. I'll try to explain it, and I hope someone has some good solutions for me:

I have two big data arrays. One that I'm browsing, with something between 50^3 and 150^3 data samples (usually between 50 and 100, rare worst case scenario 150).
For every sample, I want to make a query on another structure that is around the same size (so huge number of total combinations, I can't explore them all).

The query can't be predicted exactly but usually, it is something like :
structure has fields A B C D E F G (EDIT : in total, it's something like 10 to 20 int fields).
query is something like :
10 < A < 20 and B > 100 and D > 200.
Yes, it's really close to SQL.

I thought to put this in a database, but actually it would be a standalone database, and I can work in RAM to make it even faster (speed is an essential criteria).

I thought to try something using GPGPU but it seems it's a terrible idea and despite search can be parallel, it does't seem to be a good idea, searching an unpredictable number of results isn't a good application (if someone can tell me if my understanding has been right it would help me confirm that I should forgive this solution).
EDIT : the nubmer of results is unpredictable because of the query nature, but the it is quite low, since the purpose is to find a low number of well suited combinations

Then since I could use a DB, why not make a RAM B-Tree? it seems close to the solution, but is it? If it is, how should I build my indexes? Can I really do multidimensional indexes, since multidimensional search will always exist? probably UB-Tree or R-tree could do the job (but in my second data sample, I could have some duplicates, so doesn't it make the R-TREE non applicable?).
The thing is, I'm not sure I understand properly all those right now, so if one of you knows trees (and gpgpu, and even solutions I didn't think to), perhaps you could let me know which solution I should explore, learn, and implement?

Answer (score 0):

- GPGPU is not a suitable choice due to the fact that you are limited by their capacity and since you are not telling us the data size of these samples I am assuming that a titan x tier card will not suffice. If you could go really wild, TESLA or FirePro, then it is actually worth it since you mentioned that speed really matters. But I am going to speculate that these things are out of your budget, and considering that you have to learn CUDA or OpenCL to make something that will generally be a pain to port here and there, my take is "No".
- You mentioned that you have an unpredictable number of results and this is a bad thing. You should develop a formula that will "somewhat" calculate the amount of space which will be needed otherwise it will be disappointing to have your program work on something for quite some time only to get a capacity error/crash. On the other hand, if the RAM capacity is not sufficient, you could work "database style" fetching data from storage when needed(and this is quite bothersome to implement due to scheduling implementations etc).
- If you do have the time to go bespoke, here is a helpfull link. Remember, you are going to stumble a lot, but when you make it you will have learnt a tone of stuff:

  ```
  https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-fast-similarity-search-algorithms-and-data-structures-for-high-dimensional-vectors
  ```
- In my opinion, an in memory database is the easiest and at the same time most reliable thing to do without compromising on speed. Which one to implement is on you. I think MemSQL is a good one.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have some precisions to make I guess :  
The sample are pretty low : it's like 8 ints per sample, could grow to 16. The way I'm doing it right now is already satisfying in best cases scenarios  and is fitting in RAM. I have to improve all the "not best cases scenarios", and here I am :D
 The unpredictable number of results were actually not accurate enough : the number of results is unpredictable (because of how my query works), but the purpose of the software is to find a low number of good combinations, so things already fit in RAM

Comment: And about the in memory database, it's what I'm looking at, more or less. But once I looked at memory database, my question is : according to my specific need, isn't there a specific tree structure that fits well to my needs, and that I could use. In other words, is it possible that going to a lower level will give me more suited tools to perform my queries even faster?

Comment: To be honest, I dont know about MemSQL but most databases let you tweak the process of how things are handled to a satisfying extend. You can find almost everything you need in their respective documentation, which is a lot for every database and that is a good thing. If not, you can always ask each database team/company directly. They have their own forums which are exactly for this kind of thing. Best of luck.